# Setting the direction of flying dji from code

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I create application to control flying my drone from code. I want to add functions where I want to click on button "Left" and my aircraft will be flying left with speed which I set before, etc, for all directions. This is possible from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very possible,  look at the virtual joystick class.

Comment: If I understand correctly I can control aircraft using virtual joystick but I don't have to show and touch virtual joystick? Only send data for throttle, roll, pitch and yaw?

Comment: Correct,  virtual joystick is an SDK for controlling the aircraft in a similar fashion as if the user moved the sticks except it's code sensing the stick commands.